# How to disable highlighting of a canvas on tap for Nexus Galaxy?

Tags: android, html, mobile, html5-canvas, android-browser

I'm writing a web app that uses an HTML5 canvas and testing on a Nexus Galaxy. When the user taps on the canvas, it highlights teal for a second, even though I am calling preventDefault() on the touchstart event. I have also tried some CSS rules. How do I disable this brief highlighting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the CSS rule `-webkit-tap-highlight-color` to `transparent` on the canvas seemed to do the trick for me.

Note that I also did preventDefault and stopPropagation, so one of those might have had an effect too.

Comment: Thanks! I thought I had tried this but apparently I had a typo or something. It's working now....